# How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single HTML output file?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to export multiple jasper report to single HTML output.

for sinle PDF,its no problem.
I am unable to export multiple jasper report into a single HTML 
I have 3 jasper report,and i want to to show in a singgle HTML.

Can any one provide me dummy code ?

I want to generate a single HTML file.

Comment: EX:
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(print1,request.getRealPath("/")"/jasper/DNforDrymix1.html");

Comment: Q.How to collate multiple jrxml jasper reports into a one single HTML output file ?